# What would be the drawbacks for creating "a" tags while ommitting the href attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, w3c

What I have in mind is an implementation for automatically populating the href attribute based on what's inside the a tag. I can only express this via javascript.

Example:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var elm = links[i];
    var content = elm.innerHTML
    if (content.indexof("http") !=-1 || content.indexof("www") !=-1) {
        elm.href = content;
    } else {
        elm.href = "#";
    }
}
```

Of course this is a very basic and not too well thought javascript implementation and would cause performance and SEO issues. What I was thinking about is more along the lines of suggesting it to W3C so they can plan on a native browser implementation that would save us time while coding.

We'd be able to:

- Code an a tag without specifying a href

  ```
  <a>http://google.co.uk/</a>
  ```

  Result:

  ```
  <a href="http://google.co.uk/">http://google.co.uk/</a>
  ```
- Make blank links for prototyping

  ```
  <a>Click here</a>
  ```

  Result:

  ```
  <a href="#">Click here</a>
  ```
- Override this behaviour by specifying a href

  ```
  <a href="http://google.co.uk/">Click here</a>
  ```

  Result: Unchanged.

Had these thoughts while doing the tedious job of copying and pasting the same URL hundreds of times into href attributes while creating extensive T&Cs pages. I'm sure I'm overlooking something.

Comment: The obvious question is what if you want an `a` tag without an `href`?

Comment: @Chris so you can style it as if it is an `<a>`, then populate the `href` attribute when you need it.

Comment: @NatZimmermann: I'm not sure what you are saying. I'm saying you might want an `a` without an `href`. The above proposition assumes that all `a` tags will have an `href` which is not so (unless this changed in HTML5).

Comment: What if you're using <a> as a target for an "#" link, as in: `<a href=#chapter1>Go to Ch 1</a> .... <a name=chapter1>Chapter 1</a>`

Comment: @Joe: That was what prompted my initial comment but that does seem to have been obsoleted in HTML 5 (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element). However it does still allow for empty `a` tags so the point still stands but for different reasons. As a note I believe that nowadays any id can be the target of an anchor fragment, not just named anchor tags.

Comment: @Chris Well no, what he is asking is get the value from inside the tags, and populate the `href` attribute.

Comment: @NatZimmermann: and if the tag contents doesn't look like it should be in an `href` then it puts a `#` in the `href` instead which is different from not having an `href` at all. There is a simple if/else in the sample code that always sets the `href` to something...

Comment: The W3C have put thousands of hours of thought into their HTML standards. They're not going to change the definition of `<a>` elements to save you a bit of typing.

Comment: @Chris you never need an a tag without href, if you do you're probably thinking about buttons that do ajax calls or any other interaction on the page. In that case, use the <button> element.

Comment: @Joe if you want to use a different href then you can specify it, example 3.

Comment: @JLRishe I know the W3C spend countless hours on it, but those standards are made to facilitate our work and to provide a better experience to users.

Comment: Please just use normal links with a real url, and stop using `<a href="#">`. I'm tired of websites where I can't open many links in new tabs (or discover an ugly `javascript:void(0)` into the new tabs) just because the developer thinks that the standards are just here to annoy him.

Comment: @VinnyFonseca: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element has examples of when you might want an anchor tag without an href. Also historically (though probably there are large amounts of the web still there) in HTML 4 you would use `<a name="anchorTarget">` as the destination for `<a href="#anchorTarget">`.

Comment: @sebcap26 Following standards is all good until they don't cover the functionality you desire. That doesn't change the fact that we see it happening in the real world and we have cases where we may want to use it. It's an always evolving thing.

Comment: @Chris I saw the example, just for pragmatism's sake I always put a href="#" and and id in anchor tags. Example: <a id="anchorTarget" name="anchorTarget href="#"></a>.  Because of this I still thought it would be useful to have the implementation I mentioned on my post. Thanks for the link, I'll read that carefully.

Comment: @VinnyFonseca The `a` tag is for linking. `<a href="#">` is not a link. If you want to detect a click, you can do it with any other tag (span, button ...), and if you need a "blue and underlined" text, just use css. There is no reason in "real world" that forces you to use a link for something that's not a link.

Comment: @sebcap26 Yes, I said that in my post and other answers.

Comment: Making the browser to mutate HTML elements is nonsense... I don't know of any single HTML element that the browser will change for you. If that happens (not even in your dreams) we'll end up with a few dozens of browsers that are not implementing the "Fonseca mutation algorithm"... so now what? every time we put a simple A tag we have to care? THANK YOU VERY MUCH, you have made our lives easier!

Comment: I'm trying to keep a civilized discussion here, so your sarcasm is not appreciated. I'm also looking ahead after the whole shenanigans of implementation and browser vendor updates are gone, our lives would indeed be easier. One less attribute for us to worry about. In the same way that we don't need to declare target because they have a default value, the same could be constructed to href attributes, that's all this discussion is about. My question is "Is it worth it and what are the drawbacks?", so please try answering.

Comment: What kind of website are you designing where so many of your links actually display the URL they are linking to? Most of the links on the web actually have content that is different from their `href` so the `href` attribute isn't going anywhere. The W3C isn't going to revise their HTML standard and add a niche feature to accommodate your laziness. Perhaps you should rethink your approach to web design and actually give your links text that describes what they are instead of just their address. You may discover a newly-found need for the `href` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

The proposal would break existing code, so it is unlikely that it would have much chances of being considered very seriously. There are millions (well, billions, probably) of web pages that have `a` elements without `href` attribute, for various reasons (and such elements are valid). The proposal would make all of them functionally links, changing the meaning of documents.

There are other drawbacks too, but this one probably suffices.

Comment: I agree that would break existing code but elements and methods are being deprecated all the time. Just because we have existing a tags without href attributes doesn't mean it's the correct thing to do. It is considered a valid element but the only use case I see for using empty link is when they're buttons, and in that case it should be used the <button> element, or a div with "cursor: pointer;" and hover and active states. I don't think this drawback suffices if it helps building better document structures.

Comment: @VinnyFonseca Trying to make the CSS rules for div:visited, or button:link will make no sense! for that we have anchors... a:visited, a:link, etc...

Comment: @AdrianSalazar If it's not a link, use buttons with the required css. "A" tags are for links. button, button:hover, button:active.

Comment: As describied in the HTML5 spec, an `a` element without an `href` already serves the semantic purpose of a place where a link could be (e.g. the location for the current page's link on a navigation toolbar): "If the a element has no href attribute, then the element represents a placeholder for where a link might otherwise have been placed, if it had been relevant, consisting of just the element's contents."